# Many to many relationship without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, group-concat

I'm trying to solve a problem with many-to-many relation.

I have 3 tables:

```
Article
-------
ArticleID
FilePath
Title
Description

Author
--------
AuthorID
AuthorFName /* Father last name */
AuthorMName /* Mother last name */
AuthorName

ArticleAuthor
-------------
AuthorID
ArticleID
Foreign KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES Author(AuthorID),
FOREIGN KEY (ArticleID) REFERENCES Article(ArticleID),
PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID, ArticleID)
```

The Author table has 2 authors:

```
ID FName MName Name
-- ----- ----- ----
1  XXX   YYY   AAA
2  MMM   NNN   BBB
```

The Article:

```
ID FilePath    Title  Description (optional)
-- --------    -----  ----------------------
1  /path/file  '....' ''
```

And the ArticleAuthor

```
ArticleID AuthorID
--------- --------
1         1
1         2
```

The query I'm using now is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ArticleAuthor.ArticleID,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',' + CONCAT(AuthorFName, ' ', AuthorMName, ' ', AuthorName)
            FROM FinderSchema.Author
            WHERE Author.AuthorID = ArticleAuthor.AuthorID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS Authors
FROM FinderSchema.ArticleAuthor
    LEFT JOIN FinderSchema.Author ON ArticleAuthor.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID
GROUP BY ArticleAuthor.ArticleID, ArticleAuthor.AuthorID
```

But it returns duplicates:

```
ArticleID Authors
--------- -------
1         XXX YYY AAA
1         MMM NNN BBB
```

So, is there a way to remove the duplicates? I have been reading about simulating GROUP_CONCAT (I'm targeting sql server 2008 RC 2), and that's the answer I've found (in stackoverflow, actually), but does not work for me (or many to many relationship, maybe).

Well, if someone can help me, I'll be grateful.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try just using `GROUP BY ArticleAuthor.ArticleID`. That should give you a list of all the authors for each article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I can't **group by** only ArticleAuthor.ArticleID, SQL Server says "Column FinderSchema.ArticleAuthor.AuthorID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause", that's why I'm grouping by two columns. Actually I need all columns from article, where description has type text (which cannot be used in GROUP BY), so, I don't know what I will do once I solve this problem XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ArticleID, 
         STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + a.AuthorFName + ' ' + a.AuthorMName + ' ' + a.AuthorName 
                  FROM ArticleAuthor aa JOIN Author a 
                    ON aa.AuthorID = a.AuthorID 
                 WHERE aa.ArticleID = aa2.ArticleID 
                   FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' ) Authors
  FROM ArticleAuthor aa2
 GROUP BY ArticleID
```

Output:

```
| ARTICLEID |                 AUTHORS |
---------------------------------------
|         1 | MMM NNN BBB,XXX YYY AAA |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1752/1)** demo